# how to use input from console

Tags: java, heroku, console

I trying to deploy a simple java program on heroku that get's input from the console.

here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\u000C"); 
    String selection;
    boolean video = true;
    int cnt = 0;

    while(video){
       System.out.print("Enter cat or emu : ");           
       selection = kboard.nextLine();
       if (selection.equals("emu")){
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\emu.mp4"));
        Thread.sleep(14000);            
       }else if(selection.equals("cat")){
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\Cat Boarding.mp4"));
        Thread.sleep(12000);  
       }
       System.out.println();
       cnt++;
       if (cnt == 3) video = false;
    }
    kboard.close();   

}
```

here's the error I'm getting:

```
Enter cat or emu : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
2019-03-27T23:50:37.010138+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
2019-03-27T23:50:37.010146+00:00 app[web.1]: at gen.P1.main(P1.java:18)
```

Comment: ...how exactly do you expect the user to interact with this application? Heroku is a _web_ host. It expects applications to run a web server and respond to HTTP requests.

Comment: You could interact with it from a `heroku run bash` session. Are you doing that?

Comment: also, Heroku is a Linux host, so those `c:\` paths won't work